# MediaWiki Syntaxhighlighter on Windows Server

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, mediawiki, windows-server-2008-r2

We've installed Syntaxhighlighter for MediaWiki on Windows Server 2012 R2 according to the directions here:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight#Installation

and it is not working.  I suspect it has something to do with the line which shows how to make the pygmentize binary executable in Linux, and is completely silent on what needs to be done in a Windows environment.  I'm not incredibly familiar with Python, but the environment variable is set and in the command line I can run pygmentize in it's directory if I add the .py extension, but that doesn't fix the issues with Syntaxhighlighter whatsoever.  Without the .py extension windows doesn't see it as an executable.

So the question is: what do I do on Windows Server to make pygmentize an executable that can be used by MediaWiki's syntaxhighlighter to effectively highlight syntax?

Or maybe I'm incorrect and that isn't the issue, in which case I welcome any insights!

Comment: This seems more appropriate for a bug report than a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Do you know it's a bug?  I don't.  Your comment seems inappropriate to me.